# How to split string into list nodes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nodes

```
def add(num1,num2):
    str1 = str(num1) 
    str2 = str(num2) 
    size1 = len(str1)
    size2 = len(str2)
    carry = 0
    swap = 0
    total = []

    if (size1>size2):
        temp = str1
        str1 = str2
        str2 = temp
        temp = size1
        size1 = size2
        size2 = temp
        swap = 1

    str1 = str1[::-1]
    str2 = str2[::-1]
    
    for i in range(size1):
        t=int(str1[i])+int(str2[i])+carry
        if (t>9):
            total.append(t%10)
            carry=1
        else:
            total.append(t)
            carry=0

    for i in range(size1,size2):
        t=int(str2[i])+carry
        if (t>9):
            total.append(t%10)
            carry=1
        else:
            total.append(t)
            carry=0

    if (carry):
        total.insert(size2,1)

    str1 = str1[::-1]
    str2 = str2[::-1]
    total = total[::-1]

    if (swap==1):
        temp = str1
        str1 = str2
        str2 = temp

strTotal = "".join(map(str,total))
return strTotal
```

so, here is my code. I added two numbers using the elementary school method by adding each digit one by one. I used input as a string, it works, but now I need to split the input into list nodes, and then do the same thing. Not sure how to do it. I tried

```
digitsPerNode=4

for i in range(len(str1)):
    list1=str1[:digitsPerNode]
    i+=digitsPerNode
```

but it doesn't work. Can someone help me please? (I'm using python 3.4 version)

Comment: You want to split a string by length? Like you have "aaabbbccc" and you want `["aaa","bbb","ccc"]`?

Comment: "split the input into list nodes" - give an example input and what the list nodes should look like

Comment: @geckos yes, split the numbers into nodes and add each node one by one

Comment: if you want to do what @geckos said: `nodes = zip(*(iter(str1),) * digitsPerNode)`

Comment: Sample input and desired output, please. But it does sound like a (basic) regex should be able to do it.

Comment: @Hadus i get this error, <zip object at 0x7f516518d808> , I'm using 3.4 python is that the issue?

Comment: `list_of_nodes = list(zip(*(iter(str1),) * digitsPerNode))` It was an iterable. Now it is a list :)

Comment: @usr2564301 so the sample input add(12423532,2343253), I need to split each number into nodes, like list1=["3532","1242"] list2=["3253","234"], and then add each node one by one

Comment: You can split by len by this `def split_n(s, n): return [s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s), n)]`

Comment: @BayramJumageldiyev I see. Then `["".join(a) for a in zip(*(iter("123456"),) * 2)]`

Comment: @Hadus what if string is not divisible by digitsPerNode

Comment: I'll edit my answer

Comment: @geckos how to do it reverse? list1=[str1[i-digitsPerNode:i] for i in range(len(str1), 0, digitsPerNode)] didn't work

Comment: @BayramJumageldiyev how would you find it easier to handle? If let's say we had "123235" and "32445", should we make it into groups of ["12", "3235"] and ["3", "2445"] - or - ["1", "2", "3235"] and ["3", "2445"] - the latter has the same length for parts that have to be added

Comment: This is getting long here. @BayramJumageldiyev join in chatroom: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207217/string-adder

Comment: @Hadus if input is 123235, then list1=["3235","12"] would be easier to handle for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if input is 123235, then list1=["3235","12"]

Getting string into reversed chunks of max 4:

```
def chunkate(str_num, n=4):
    s = "".join(reversed(str_num))
    a = [s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s), n)]
    return ["".join(list(reversed(k))) for k in a]

print(chunkate("123235"))
# prints: ['3235', '12']
```